# System.Drawing namespace could not refer in windows phone 8.0

Tags: windows-phone-8

How to Refer the system.Drawing namespace in windows phone8.0 application

some error occur

i need to call Bitmap class but its not work

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there is either a System.Drawing namespace or Bitmap class in WP8. If you are looking for BitmapImage then it can be found in the System.Windows.Media.Imaging namespace.

Hope this helps.

Comment: but i want Bitmap object.. in System.Windows.Media.Imaging namespace there is BitmapImage object only

Comment: That is exactly what I said...I also said I do not think there is a Bitmap object for Windows Phone 8

Comment: thank u sir... in AviWriter class i couldnt pass Bitmap Object in Windows Phone 8.0 Then only i asked